# IronPython and C# - Script Access to C# Objects

Tags: c#, ironpython

Consider the code below:

```
ScriptRuntimeSetup setup = Python.CreateRuntimeSetup(null);
ScriptRuntime runtime = new ScriptRuntime(setup);
ScriptEngine engine = Python.GetEngine(runtime);
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();

scope.SetVariable("message", "Hello, world!");
string script = @"print message";
ScriptSource source = scope.Engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(script, SourceCodeKind.Statements);
source.Execute();
```

This code yields the following exception:

> Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime.UnboundNameException
>   was unhandled   Message="name
>   'message' is not defined"

What am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It should be "source.Execute(scope);" instead of "source.Execute();"

Answer (score 3):

Found this: [A 3 minute guide to embedding IronPython in a C# application](http://www.secretgeek.net/host_ironpython.asp).